# Sass custom bootstrap stylesheet has no effect of page/inspect element

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Under app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

I'll have something like:

```
@import 'bootstrap';

.navbar {
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

I'll look at my localhost and no changes occur(my inspect element does not show any changes either on the nav tag, i.e. font-size is still set to 16px in the inspect element). Why is this?

The `!important` addition will not work either btw.

A few questions that perhaps could lead me to the right answer if no one can from the given information:
What is the `@import 'bootstrap';` purpose? 
If my view is for example views/pages/home.html.erb can I still edit the bootstrap css from a custom sass stylesheet in application.css.scss ?

I think there must have been something wring with the setup of the custom stylesheet because it is not being read at all. I have already successfully added a Bootstrap carousel to the page but did not do any custom styling on it. This leads me to believe that Bootstrap is setup properly but not the stylesheet. Any advice?

Comment: Have you compiled the SCSS files ?

Comment: Not sure what this means, how do I complie SCSS files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap (and most popular frameworks) consist of two elements, JS & CSS for most of their functionality.
Carousel is a JS component so it will work fine as long as you reference the *.js file.

With regards to Sass, in order to compile your *.scss file (i.e. create a *.css file), you need some form of compiler. If you are not sure how to do this (and I don't think this is the correct place to be explaining it), then I highly recommend you check out some Sass resources like this : [Sass lang](http://sass-lang.com). They give a great explanation on what you need to do.

Comment: I am on ruby on rails. Adding the proper gems to the gemfile, bundle installing them & requiring them in your particular stylesheet should be enough according to the documentation here:   https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass I believe the gem's take care of the compiling... Am I incorrect on this?

Comment: Not sure how Ruby on Rails works, but if you still have issues you might want to use something like Koala: http://koala-app.com/